# Python:How do I print not only the final value after running the for statement, but also the middle output?

Tags: python, for-loop

everybody. 
I want to make a code with a different name every time the For Moon is executed.

```
for i in range(10):
    SD="Vega"+str(i)
    print(SD)

print(SD)
```

After executing the code above
The result is as follows:

```
Vega0
Vega1
Vega2
Vega3
Vega4
Vega5
Vega6
Vega7
Vega8
Vega9
Vega9
```

What should I do if I want to print a value not just for VD9 but also for VD2 after all the for statements have been executed in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the intermediate values somewhere.

```
stored_values = []
for i in range(10):
    SD="Vega" + str(i)
    stored_values.append(SD)
print(SD)
```

or if you just want them as a long string that looks just like a print statement

```
SD = ''
for i in range(10):
    SD+="Vega" + str(i) + "\n"
print(SD)
```

Comment: So what do I do if I want to print Vga3?

Comment: if you use the list format (like in my answer), you would do `print(stored_values[3])`

Answer (score 1):

you can store all the SD values in a list and access it later via indexing.

```
 list_sd = [] # initialize empty list
 for i in range(10):
     SD="Vega"+str(i)
     print(SD)         # prints "Vega1", "Vega2" etc.
     list_sd.append(SD) # appends the respective SD value to your list
print(SD) # prints the last VD, "Vega9" in this case
print(list_sd[i]) # i being the index, so list_vd[1] prints "Vega1" and so on...
```